# The result set is not updatable java-Mssql

Tags: java, sql-server, database-connection

I am working with java and Mssql. But I am a beginner. I have connected sql but when I want to insert data in sql, I have a problem.

code:

```
 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
                 try{
                 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                 Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Hastane;user=Test                 ;password=Sz04022010;");
                 Statement komut = con.createStatement();
                 ResultSet as=komut.executeQuery("select max(PersonelID) from  dbo.tbl_personel");
                 int a=Integer.parseInt(as.getString("SicilNo"));
                 a++;
                 jLabel13.setText(Integer.toString(a));}
                 catch (SQLException ex) {     
                Logger.getLogger(Personel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Personel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             } }
```

ERROR-------------------

```
Tem 17, 2014 11:47:01 PM Personel jButton1ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set is not updatable.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.throwNotUpdatable(SQLServerResultSet.java:409)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.verifyResultSetIsUpdatable(SQLServerResultSet.java:420)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.moveToInsertRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:4232)
    at Personel.jButton1ActionPerformed(Personel.java:367)
    at Personel.access$100(Personel.java:24)
    at Personel$2.actionPerformed(Personel.java:153)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: What is 'SicilNo' in the query?

Comment: Just a side note: You do not need to laod the driver every time your button is pressed. Once is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add as.next() between these rows:

```
ResultSet as=komut.executeQuery("select max(PersonelID) from  dbo.tbl_personel");
int a=Integer.parseInt(as.getString("SicilNo"));
```

This should help

Comment: Doesn't he also need to use some specific Cursor? There is some faint memory of me running into that trap a long long time ago in a galaxy far away...

Answer (score 0):

it is last case.thanks ;)

```
    {

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
           try{
                     Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Hastane;user=Test;password=Sz04022010;");
                     Statement komut = con.createStatement();// TODO add your handling code here:
                     ResultSet as=komut.executeQuery("SELECT *  FROM dbo.tbl_personel WHERE PersonelID=( SELECT max(PersonelID) FROM dbo.tbl_personel)\n");
                     as.next();
                     int a=Integer.parseInt(as.getString("PersonelID"));
                       a++;
                       jLabel13.setText(Integer.toString(a));}
            catch (SQLException ex) {     
                Logger.getLogger(Personel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Personel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 

         //Connection con=null;

        }          
    }
```